# Looking at potentially 100,000 users/entries to capture data

Tags: users, database

Looking at a small site build, but potentially capturing Names, Email and Addresses /custom fields, then dumping into a csv.

There's no user activation, but any potential issues with so many entries in the sql database in any one go?

User Registration in Craft seems to fit the bill nicely for us.

Any experience or notes welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We've seen Craft installs with several hundred thousand users/assets/entries running along fine.

You'll just need to be smart with how you're pulling data out on the template side and use caching where appropriate and you should be fine.